# Find a basis for the null space of a linear transformation T when we are given the spanning set of the range of T

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^{5}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{4}$
  be a linear transformation of the form $Tx=Ax$
  where $A$
  is a matrix of appropriate size with entries in the field of real numbers. Suppose that the range of T is spanned by the vectors 
$\alpha_{1}=\left(1,1,2,4\right),\alpha_{2}=\left(2,-1,-5,2\right),\alpha_{3}=\left(1,-1,-4,0\right),\alpha_{4}=\left(2,1,1,6\right)$ . Find a basis for the null space of $T$

Comment: No one can, because $\ker T$ is not univocally determined by "the" (**a**) spanning set of $\operatorname{im}T$, unless $T$ turns out to be injective (which cannot be in this case).

Comment: By the way, you *might* be able to say something about the null space of $A^t$; did you perhaps lose a superscript when you asked the question?

Comment: No, I didn't miss any subscript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a basis for the range of a linear transformation T when we are given the spanning set of the null space of T](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170290/find-a-basis-for-the-range-of-a-linear-transformation-t-when-we-are-given-the-sp)

Comment: @ja72 Not quite a duplicate, but certainly related. In the other question, you’re given the null space and asked to find the range.

Comment: Have you done any work on this yourself? If so, please show it in your question so that we can see where you’re having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The given vectors span the image of 
$$
P = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & -5 & -4 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 2 & 0 & 6 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the image of 
$$
Q = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2  \\
0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & -5 & -4 & 1 \\
0 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 6 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

while a basis for the kernel of $P$ is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and a basis for the kernel of $Q$ is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
showing that the basis cannot be determined uniquely from the information given.

(This is merely an amplification of G. Sassatelli's comment.)

Comment: What is $Q$ here ?

Comment: The second matrix, which never got renamed during cut-and-paste. Fixed.