# Find a basis for the range of a linear transformation T when we are given the spanning set of the null space of T

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^{5}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{4}$
  be a linear transformation of the form Tx=Ax
  where $A$
  is a matrix of appropriate size with entries in the field of real numbers. Suppose that the null space of T is spanned by the vectors 
$\alpha_{1}=\left(-1,0,1,2,0\right),\alpha_{2}=\left(3,4,-2,5,1\right),\alpha_{3}=\left(2,4,-1,7,1\right)$.  Find a basis for the range of $T$

Comment: Just as I asked for your previous question, have you done any work on this yourself? If so, please show it in your question so that we can see where you’re having trouble.

Comment: Once you know how to solve [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2170120/265466), you should be able to do this one as well. The underlying principles are the same.

Answer (score 1):

We have $α_1, α_2$ are basis of the Null space (because $ α_3=α_1 + α_2$)  and then $α_1, α_2$  are linearly independent and contained in $\Bbb R^5$ lets complete that to a basis of $\Bbb R^5$ let $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ be the vectors that complete the basis, then $T $ is determined by wuere does it sends the basis, note that  $T(α_i)=0$ for $i=1,2$ so the image of T must be spanned by $T(v_1)$, $T (v_2) $ and $T(v_3) $.

Comment: In this case $v_1 =(1,0,0,0,0)$, $v_2=(0,1,0,0,0) $ and $v_3=(0,0,1,0,0)$ are possible vectors that complete the basis

Answer (score 0):

First of all, by the dimension theorem for linear maps, we get that $$5=\dim(\ker(T))+\dim(\text{im}(T)).$$
Hence $\dim(\text{im}(T))=3$. This means that you need three independent vectors. Now, you have that $\mathbb{R}^5=\ker(T)\oplus U$ for some $U$. Clearly if $v\in U\setminus \ker(T)$, then $T(v)\neq 0$. You can easily show that a basis of $U$ is a desired basis. So you can extend the basis of $\ker(T)$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$ and the extra vectors will do the job.

Concretely, you can add the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$ to the two independent vectors you already have and remove those that are in the span of the previous ones, this procedure ends and will give you a basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$ containing a basis of $\ker(T)$ and $U$.

Comment: The response is correct but do note that the given "basis" is not linearly independent as $ α_3=  α_1+ α_2$.

Comment: Absolutely right, I didn't check that. Edited my answer and upvoted yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Find a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_r\}$for any complement of the null space. A convenient one is its orthogonal complement, a basis for which you can find by row-reducing the matrix that has your three vectors as rows. Then $\{Tv_1,\dots,Tv_r\}$ will be a basis for the range of $T$.